# Proving the upper- and lowerbound of a probability measure set-intersection, given certain conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

So I've been going in circles over the last few hours of this seemingly simple problem:

"Let $(X,F,\mu)$ be a probability space. Let $A,B,C$ be sets contained in $F$, with

$\mu(A \cap B) \ge \frac{1}{2}$, $\mu(A \cap C) \ge \frac{1}{2}$, $\mu(B \cap C) \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

Show that
$\frac{1}{4} \le \mu(A \cap B \cap C) \le \min\{\mu(A \cap B), \mu(A \cap C), \mu(B \cap C)\}$".

Honestly, I'm plain simply stuck. I've been trying to see if I could get something useful out of De Morgan's identities as well as the distributive laws, but I seem to either be going in circles or end up with something not very useful due to unions I can not identify or the lack of information about $A$, $B$ and $C$. Same thing with the strongly additive property of a measure, which is only stated for the intersection of two sets in my book.

I feel like this should be simple, but I'm staring myself blind at this problem. Can anyone offer some guidance?

Comment: The second inequality follows from subadditivity (as $A\cap B$, $A\cap C$, and $B\cap C$ are subsets of $A\cap B\cap C$).